# Amazon RDS PostgreSQL: how to create user?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have created 3 databases in one RDS DB instance.
The owner of these databases is user postgres.
I'd like to create the new power user.
When I am trying to create it I receive:
"User 'postgres' has no privileges to edit users"
But it is the one user which I can use.
How I can create the new user?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like you need to use CREATE ROLE and assign the rds_superuser role to the new user. It's documented here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Roles

and I'll paste the instructions too:

```
postgres=> create role testuser with password 'testuser' login;   
CREATE ROLE   
postgres=> grant rds_superuser to testuser;   
GRANT ROLE   
postgres=>
```

Comment: `grant rds_superuser to testuser;` doesn't seem to work